# Executing a command in every eloquent connection

Tags: sql-server, laravel

I just found I need to execute the following command

```
'SET ANSI_NULLS, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, ANSI_WARNINGS, ANSI_PADDING ON'
```

in every connection to my MSSQL server. Otherwise, I get errors.

> QueryException in Connection.php line 624: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General
>   error: 7405 General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL
>   Server [7405] (severity 16) [(null)] (SQL: select dni from
>   tableCont WHERE lngNumeroFixe = 428224)
>
> in Connection.php line 624
>   at Connection->runQueryCallback('select dni from tblCont WHERE lngNumeroFixe = 428224', array(),
>   object(Closure)) in Connection.php line 580
>       at Connection->run('select dni from tableCont WHERE lngNumeroFixe = 428224', array(), object(Closure)) in Connection.php
>   line 297
>       at Connection->select('select dni from tblCont WHERE lngNumeroFixe = 428224')

Where should I do that? Of course I can overwrite the connection function in `vendor\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\SqlServerConnector`, and force there execution before returning the connection. Of course that's ugly and dangerous.

But where else?

Comment: Perhaps it might be better to try and address the errors, rather than avoiding/ignoring them?

Comment: @Larnu Like you are doing with my question?

Comment: Are all these settings set to off in the database?

Comment: It doesn't depend on the database, but in the connection. Anyway, I cannot modify the database since it is already used by other applications and unfortunately I can't go changing anything I need just because of my application.

Comment: what errors do you get ? I agree with Lamu it would be better to investigate what is causing the errors before using a patch like this

Comment: I'm not ignoring your question at all. If I were, I wouldn't have commented. My point is that you shouldn't be ignoring or avoiding the errors you have but trying to fix them, and inferring that your question really appears to be an xy question. Then you don't need to try and use those commands at the start of every statement; and that does solve your problem.

Comment: Ok, I updated the question with the error.

Comment: Those are the php errors, what about SQL Server's error message(s)? If your query is as simple as `select dni from tableCont WHERE lngNumeroFixe = 428224` then I don't expect that to cause an error on it's own.

Comment: Ok, listen: I need those options to be set in the connection, because the default connection doesn't include them. The way to do it is to execute those lines. The same thing you do with the "SET NAMES UTF-8" to set charset to be UTF-8. Do you know where to execute them? You can see the error code is 7405, which with a bit of search I found this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/deb1a69b-1dfb-4288-b272-bbc060367cd1/error-7405-severity-16?forum=sqlkjappmsmgmt to be the solution.